# Tailwind CSS - Wrapping DIV to content and centering

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have unordered list of social icons under DIV tags. I would like to wrap DIV to its content and center, for this purpose I used flex-wrap and mx-auto however DIV still occupies full screen size and its content is not centered.

```
<div class="flex-wrap mx-auto">
        <ul class="hidden sm:inline-flex gap-4 py-2 px-5" >
            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" class="w-5 h-5 transition ease-in-out delay-30 fill-A200 hover:scale-110 hover:fill-G50 duration-300" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> 
                    <path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"></path>
                 </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" class="w-5 h-5 transition ease-in-out delay-30 fill-A200 hover:scale-110 hover:fill-G50 duration-300"  role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> 
                    <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/> 
                    <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M12 2c2.717 0 3.056.01 4.122.06 1.065.05 1.79.217 2.428.465.66.254 1.216.598 1.772 1.153a4.908 4.908 0 0 1 1.153 1.772c.247.637.415 1.363.465 2.428.047 1.066.06 1.405.06 4.122 0 2.717-.01 3.056-.06 4.122-.05 1.065-.218 1.79-.465 2.428a4.883 4.883 0 0 1-1.153 1.772 4.915 4.915 0 0 1-1.772 1.153c-.637.247-1.363.415-2.428.465-1.066.047-1.405.06-4.122.06-2.717 0-3.056-.01-4.122-.06-1.065-.05-1.79-.218-2.428-.465a4.89 4.89 0 0 1-1.772-1.153 4.904 4.904 0 0 1-1.153-1.772c-.248-.637-.415-1.363-.465-2.428C2.013 15.056 2 14.717 2 12c0-2.717.01-3.056.06-4.122.05-1.066.217-1.79.465-2.428a4.88 4.88 0 0 1 1.153-1.772A4.897 4.897 0 0 1 5.45 2.525c.638-.248 1.362-.415 2.428-.465C8.944 2.013 9.283 2 12 2zm0 5a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 5 5 0 0 0 0-10zm6.5-.25a1.25 1.25 0 0 0-2.5 0 1.25 1.25 0 0 0 2.5 0zM12 9a3 3 0 1 1 0 6 3 3 0 0 1 0-6z"></path> 
                </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" class="w-5 h-5 transition ease-in-out delay-30 fill-A200 hover:scale-110 hover:fill-G50 duration-300" role="img"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8.051 1.999h.089c.822.003 4.987.033 6.11.335a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 1.415 1.42c.101.38.172.883.22 1.402l.01.104.022.26.008.104c.065.914.073 1.77.074 1.957v.075c-.001.194-.01 1.108-.082 2.06l-.008.105-.009.104c-.05.572-.124 1.14-.235 1.558a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415 1.42c-1.16.312-5.569.334-6.18.335h-.142c-.309 0-1.587-.006-2.927-.052l-.17-.006-.087-.004-.171-.007-.171-.007c-1.11-.049-2.167-.128-2.654-.26a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415-1.419c-.111-.417-.185-.986-.235-1.558L.09 9.82l-.008-.104A31.4 31.4 0 0 1 0 7.68v-.123c.002-.215.01-.958.064-1.778l.007-.103.003-.052.008-.104.022-.26.01-.104c.048-.519.119-1.023.22-1.402a2.007 2.007 0 0 1 1.415-1.42c.487-.13 1.544-.21 2.654-.26l.17-.007.172-.006.086-.003.171-.007A99.788 99.788 0 0 1 7.858 2h.193zM6.4 5.209v4.818l4.157-2.408L6.4 5.209z"></path> 
                </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.tiktok.com">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" class="w-5 h-5 transition ease-in-out delay-30 fill-A200 hover:scale-110 hover:fill-G50 duration-300" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"> 
                    <path d="M16.708 0.027c1.745-0.027 3.48-0.011 5.213-0.027 0.105 2.041 0.839 4.12 2.333 5.563 1.491 1.479 3.6 2.156 5.652 2.385v5.369c-1.923-0.063-3.855-0.463-5.6-1.291-0.76-0.344-1.468-0.787-2.161-1.24-0.009 3.896 0.016 7.787-0.025 11.667-0.104 1.864-0.719 3.719-1.803 5.255-1.744 2.557-4.771 4.224-7.88 4.276-1.907 0.109-3.812-0.411-5.437-1.369-2.693-1.588-4.588-4.495-4.864-7.615-0.032-0.667-0.043-1.333-0.016-1.984 0.24-2.537 1.495-4.964 3.443-6.615 2.208-1.923 5.301-2.839 8.197-2.297 0.027 1.975-0.052 3.948-0.052 5.923-1.323-0.428-2.869-0.308-4.025 0.495-0.844 0.547-1.485 1.385-1.819 2.333-0.276 0.676-0.197 1.427-0.181 2.145 0.317 2.188 2.421 4.027 4.667 3.828 1.489-0.016 2.916-0.88 3.692-2.145 0.251-0.443 0.532-0.896 0.547-1.417 0.131-2.385 0.079-4.76 0.095-7.145 0.011-5.375-0.016-10.735 0.025-16.093z"></path>
                 </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" class="w-5 h-5 transition ease-in-out delay-30 fill-A200 hover:scale-110 hover:fill-G50 duration-300" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> 
                    <path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"></path>
                </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Please, advice how can I make DIV centered on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Add `w-fit` to the div container.

**Solution 2:**

Add `flex` and `justify-center` classes to the div container.

***PS: in both cases you don't need* `flex-wrap` *class***

**Output:**

[image]